# IPV6 dual stack mode check is ipv6 kernel module is loaded

Tags: c++, linux, kernel, ipv6

I am trying to run my server in ipv6 dual stack mode. Inside the code I need to make decisions to run in dual stack mode if ipv6 module is loaded or in normal mode if ipv6 is not enabled. Is there way to query if the module is loaded in the kernel.

I am trying to get the module information using query_module() api defined in . It looks like query_module is only supported in kernel 2.6 and below. What is the alternative method to query if a particular module is loaded or not.

Are there any alternative ways to achieve this ?

Thank you

Comment: You could also just try to create an IPv6 socket and see if you get one.

Comment: The problem is, I need to use the same port. The dual stack mode solves this problem

Comment: Querying to see if a module is loaded is bad idea since ipv6 could be compiled directly into the kernel, and not as a module

Comment: You don't need to, and should not, bother to check the kernel modules to see if you can use IPv6. For instance, a system might have IPv6 modules loaded, but not have IPv6 connectivity beyond the local link (effectively none) or at all.

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple server sockets created in my application at different modules and to have a global check before switching to old style binding instead of a dual stack mode.

```
 union usockaddr {
      struct sockaddr sa;
      struct sockaddr_in sin;
       struct sockaddr_in6 sin6;
     };

is_ipv6_enabled()
{        
        SOCKET tsock;
        union usockaddr socketaddr;    
        int on=1;
        static int checked = -1;

        if(checked != -1)
            return checked;

        memset(&socketaddr, 0, sizeof(socketaddr));
        socketaddr.sin6.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
        socketaddr.sin6.sin6_port = htons((uint16_t)0); // Random port
        socketaddr.sin6.sin6_addr = in6addr_any;


        if( (tsock = socket(socketaddr.sa.sa_family, SOCK_STREAM, 6)) == INVALID_SOCKET ||
            setsockopt(tsock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (const char *) &on, sizeof(on)) != 0 ||
            bind(tsock, &socketaddr.sa, sizeof(socketaddr)) != 0 ||
            listen(tsock,SOMAXCONN) != 0){
              checked = 0;
         }
         else {
            checked = 1;
         }

         closesocket(tsock);

         return checked;
}
```

Comment: Please explain what is wrong with the question and answer ? If you have better solution then please explain. I don't want me asking all the my previous users to dump the old product which knows only about the old port.